# ISO 8583 message numeric in byte

Tags: iso8583, j8583

Config:

```
<template type="0200">
        <field num="3" type="NUMERIC" length="6">000000</field>
        <field num="11" type="NUMERIC" length="6" />
        <field num="24" type="NUMERIC" length="3" />
</template>
```

Code:

```
mfact.setTraceNumberGenerator(new SimpleTraceGenerator((int) (System
                    .currentTimeMillis() % 100000)));
m = mfact.newMessage(0x200);
m.setBinary(false);

m.setValue(24, 109, IsoType.NUMERIC, 3);
String strMsg = new String(msg.writeData());
```

I get the following result for `strMsg`

```
05002020010000000000920000058121109
```

Please look at the last 3 number.

The result should be:

```
050020200100000000009200000581210109
```

Why is the `field 24` is `109`, I thought it should be `0109`?

Comment: It seems numeric fields are being encoded in binary when you ask for ascii and in ascii when you ask for binary.

Comment: What is the result of `msg.debugString()`?